# How to Iterate Functions using Frida

Tags: javascript, java, frida

I have the ff Java code:

```
public class Class1 {

    public boolean Function1() {
    }

    public boolean Function2() {
    }

    public boolean Function3() {
    }
    ...
    public boolean FunctionX() {
    }
}
```

And I wanted to hook all these functions with Frida. For example:

```
Java.perform(function(){
    var classVar = Java.use("Class1");

    classVar.Function1.implementation = function(){
        // code here
    };

    classVar.Function2.implementation = function(){
        // code here
    };

    classVar.Function2.implementation = function(){
        // code here
    };

    ...

    classVar.FunctionX.implementation = function(){
        // code here
    };
});
```

Since these functions belong to the same class, I wonder if I could hook all these functions by putting them in an array and loop through them? That way my code will be shorter.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate class methods with `Java.use("com.Class1").class.getDeclaredMethods()`

Full example can be found at https://github.com/iddoeldor/frida-snippets#trace-class

Comment: Thanks. That looks useful. However, what if I only wanted to hook "some" methods? For example, I only wanted Function1, Function3, Function 5, etc.

Comment: You use filter the list with `.filter(method => condition)`